# FuelSDK C# Send Email

Tags: send-email

I'm trying to send a new email to a list of subscribers via FuelSDK C#.

1) Should I be using a Send or a TriggeredSend? Based on the SDK documentation, it appears that I should be using Send.

2) Do you have any examples for this using FuelSDK C#?

3) Is version .9 the latest for FuelSDK?

4) Is there additional documentation available online, pdf or ????

5) Can these records be viewed (e.g. user initiated sends folder) if created via the API. I currently can view emails, lists and subscribers that have been created using the API.

5) The send.EmailSendDefinition and the send.List is null after post. They are set prior to the post, the information appears when I examine the value via the watch window, but when I get this record, the values are null. One additional note, no emails are sent. See code example below.  Suggestions?????

// Create client

```
FuelSDK.ET_Client et_Client = new FuelSDK.ET_Client(Models.Utility.ClientParameters());
```

// Create email send definition

```
FuelSDK.ET_EmailSendDefinition et_EmailSendDefinition = new  FuelSDK.ET_EmailSendDefinition();
    //et_EmailSendDefinition.AuthStub = et_Client;
    et_EmailSendDefinition.Name = send.Name;
    et_EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey = send.CustomerKey;
    et_EmailSendDefinition.Description = send.Description;
    et_EmailSendDefinition.FolderID =   Models.Utility.GetFolderId(send.FolderName, et_Client, "userinitiatedsends");
    et_EmailSendDefinition.CategoryID = (et_EmailSendDefinition.FolderID ?? 0);
 if (send.SendClassification.CustomerKey != null || send.SendClassification.ObjectID != null)
    {
    et_EmailSendDefinition.SendClassification = new FuelSDK.SendClassification()
    {
    CustomerKey = send.SendClassification.CustomerKey,
    ObjectID = send.SendClassification.ObjectID
    };
}

if (send.SenderProfile.CustomerKey != null || send.SenderProfile.ObjectID != null)
   {
    et_EmailSendDefinition.SenderProfile = new FuelSDK.SenderProfile()
     {
      CustomerKey = send.SenderProfile.CustomerKey,
      ObjectID = send.SenderProfile.ObjectID
      };
    }

 if (send.DeliveryProfile.CustomerKey != null || send.DeliveryProfile.ObjectID != null)
    {
    et_EmailSendDefinition.DeliveryProfile = new FuelSDK.DeliveryProfile()
      {
       CustomerKey = send.DeliveryProfile.CustomerKey,
       ObjectID = send.DeliveryProfile.ObjectID
       };
     }
     et_EmailSendDefinition.DeduplicateByEmail = send.DeduplicateByEmail;
     et_EmailSendDefinition.SuppressTracking = send.SuppressTracking;
  // Post send
  FuelSDK.ET_Send et_Send = new FuelSDK.ET_Send();
    et_Send.AuthStub = et_Client;
    et_Send.CustomerKey = send.CustomerKey;
    et_Send.Email = new FuelSDK.ET_Email() { ID = send.EmailID };
    et_Send.EmailName = send.EmailName;
    et_Send.List = send.ConvertList(send.Lists);
    et_Send.Subject = send.Subject;
    et_Send.SendWindowOpen = send.SendWindowOpen;
    et_Send.SendWindowClose = send.SendWindowClose;
    et_Send.SendLimit = send.SendLimit;
    et_Send.IsMultipart = send.IsMultipart;
  if (send.SendDate != null) 
     et_Send.SendDate = (DateTime)send.SendDate;
     et_Send.FromAddress = send.FromAddress;
     et_Send.FromName = send.FromName;
     et_Send.EmailSendDefinition = et_EmailSendDefinition;
     FuelSDK.PostReturn postReturn = et_Send.Post();

 // If not posted...

 if (!postReturn.Status)
  {
  errorResults.Add(string.Format("Error posting send '{0}' : '{1}'. {2}", send.Name, send.CustomerKey, (postReturn.Results.Length > 0 ? postReturn.Results[0].StatusMessage : postReturn.Message)).Trim());
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, errorResults);
  }
```